# Nginx rewrite requests to subdomain.tld/files/* to external domain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'd like to rewrite all requests to Nginx matching `http://*.examle.tld/files/*` to `http://$1.otherdomain.tld/files/?file=$2`. I'd also like to rewrite the same request without the subdomain i.e. `http://example.tld/files/*` to `http://otherdomain.tld/files/?file=$1`

The reason for this is to use production files from local development without having to sync folders.

This is what I've got so far, however without success:

```
location / {
    ...
    rewrite ^http://(\w+)\.(.*)/files/(.*) http://$1.otherdomain.tld/inc/reader.php?file=$3;
    rewrite ^.*/files/(.*) http://$1.otherdomain.tld/inc/reader.php?file=$1;
    ...
}
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the server name as part of the `rewrite` directive's regex. If you have a `server` block with a wild card `server_name` as described [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names), you can use a named capture for use later within the block.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?<sub>\w+\.)?example\.tld$;

    location /files/ {
        rewrite ^/files(.*)$ http://${sub}otherdomain.tld/files/?file=$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.